# react-native: Overlay content over Modal

Tags: react-native, z-index

Android allows rendering a Modal on top of another Modal thus allowing the ability to overlay content on top of a Modal. iOS unfortunately doesn't show the second Modal. I've tried several combinations of zIndex and ordering Components with no luck. Is there no way to overlay content on top of a Modal on iOS?